# Balanced Error Rate as metric function

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano, keras

I am trying to solve a binary classification problem with the sequential model from Keras
and have to meet a given [Balanced Error Rate (BER)](http://www.damienfrancois.be/blog/files/modelperfcheatsheet.pdf?search=Balanced)

So I thought it would be a good idea to use the BER instead of accuracy as a metric.

My custom metric implementation for BER looks like this:

```py
def balanced_error_rate(y_true, y_pred):
    labels = theano.shared(np.asmatrix([[0, 1]], dtype='int8'))
    label_matrix = K.repeat_elements(labels, K.shape(y_true)[0], axis=1)
    true_matrix = K.repeat_elements(y_true, K.shape(labels)[0], axis=1)
    pred_matrix = K.repeat_elements(K.round(y_pred), K.shape(labels)[0], axis=1)

    class_lens = K.sum(K.equal(label_matrix, true_matrix), axis=1)
    return K.sum(K.sum(class_lens - K.sum(K.equal(label_matrix, K.not_equal(true_matrix,pred_matrix)), axis=1), axis=0)/class_lens, axis=0)/2
```

The idea is to create a matrix from the available labels and compare it to the input data (then sum the ones) to get the number of elements of this label....

My problem is that:

```
> K.shape(y_true) 
Shape.0    


> Typeinfo:

> type(y_true)
<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>

> type(K.shape(y_true))
<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
```

...and I can't find out why.

---

I am now looking for:

A way to get the array dimensions / an explanation why `shape` acts like it does / the reason why `y_true` seems to have `0` dimensions

**or**

A method to create a tensor matrix with a given with/height by repeating a given row/column vector.

**or**

A smarter solution to calculate the BER using tensor functions.

Comment: Does it return `0` of type `int`? Can you print the type information (e.g. the result of `type(x)`)?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A way to get the array dimensions / an explanation why shape acts like it does / the reason why `y_true` seems to have 0 dimensions

The deal with `print` and abstraction libraries like Theano is that you usually do not get the values but a represenation of the value. So if you do

```
print(foo.shape)
```

You won't get the actual shape but a representation of the operation that is done at runtime. Since this is all computed on an external device the computation is not run immediately but only after creating a function with appropriate inputs (or calling `foo.shape.eval()`).

Another way to print the value is to use `theano.printing.Print` when using the value, e.g.:

```
shape = theano.printing.Print('shape of foo')(foo.shape)
# use shape (not foo.shape!)
```

> A method to create a tensor matrix with a given with/height by repeating a given row/column vector.

See [`theano.tensor.repeat`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.repeat) for that. Example in numpy (usage is quite similar):

```
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> x.repeat(3, axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks that pointed me in the right direction. There is still a logical error somewhere because the function returns values >1 but I think I can figure that out on my own - or create a new question if I can't. (I suspect I mixed up equal and bitwise_and)

Comment: You can always create a new question here on SO.

Comment: Well I got it working ....but... I realized that the number of classelements I calculate there are per batch... and completely useless :-/